# Найти все одинаковые дивы и скрыть?

Tags: javascript

На сайте присутствует по несколько одинаковых дивов, и всегда они разные, как найти у каждого дива дубликат и скрыть его? Что бы осталось по одному из видов дива. Отличаются они значение `data-name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что обрабатываемые элементы не вложены друг в друга и нужно оставить первый из каждой группы. Это можно сделать так (но следует проверить поддержку браузерами используемых возможностей):

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var used = Object.create(null)
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("[data-name]")
  
  for (var q=0; q<elems.length; ++q) {
    var name = elems[q].dataset.name
    
    if (used[name]) {
      elems[q].remove()
    } else {
      used[name] = true
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<button>Remove</button>

<div data-name=a>a-1</div>
<div data-name=b>b-1</div>
<div data-name=a>a-2</div>
<div data-name=a>a-3</div>
<div data-name=b>b-2</div>
<div data-name=b>b-3</div>
<div data-name=a>a-4</div>
<div data-name=c>c-1</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы правильно меня поняли, очень помогли!

Comment: на вашем примере почему то работает, а все мои дивы он скрывает почему то, не оставляет ни одного

Comment: А все, разобрался, нужно было вырать все дивы по классу нужному, спасибо большое еще раз, все работает